# WKInterfaceTable how to identify button in each of the row?

Tags: ios, watchkit, wkinterfacetable

I had for loop out 3 buttons in the table row and it will redirect to the related details when pressed.

Problem is how to identify which button users click? I have tried `setAccessibilityLabel` and `setValue forKey` but both do not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use *delegate* in your **CustomRow** Class.

In **CustomRow.h** file:

```
@protocol CustomRowDelegate;

@interface CustomRow : NSObject
@property (weak, nonatomic) id <CustomRowDelegate> deleagte;

@property (assign, nonatomic) NSInteger index;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet WKInterfaceButton *button;
@end

@protocol CustomRowDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)didSelectButton:(WKInterfaceButton *)button onCellWithIndex:(NSInteger)index;

@end
```

In **CustomRow.m** file you need to add *IBAction* connected to your button in IB. Then handle this action:

```
- (IBAction)buttonAction {
    [self.deleagte didSelectButton:self.button onCellWithIndex:self.index];
}
```

In **YourInterfaceController.m** class in method where you configure rows:

```
- (void)configureRows {

    NSArray *items = @[*anyArrayWithData*];

    [self.tableView setNumberOfRows:items.count withRowType:@"Row"];
    NSInteger rowCount = self.tableView.numberOfRows;

    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {

        CustomRow* row = [self.tableView rowControllerAtIndex:i];

        row.deleagte = self;
        row.index = i;
    }
 }
```

Now you have just to implement your *delegate* method:

```
- (void)didSelectButton:(WKInterfaceButton *)button onCellWithIndex:(NSInteger)index {
     NSLog(@" button pressed on row at index: %d", index);
}
```

Comment: `[ContactController didSelectButton:onCellWithIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance `

Why does my code has this error? I follow your code exactly? does my button linking has problem?

Comment: _@Ngo Yen Sern_, didSelectButton:onCellWithIndex: should be called not from controller class, but from *Cell* class. And your controller should be a delegate of the cell

Answer (score 3):

If a button is pressed, WatchKit will call the following method:

```
- (void)table:(WKInterfaceTable *)table didSelectRowAtIndex:(NSInteger)rowIndex
```

Use the rowIndex parameter to decide which action should be done then.

Answer (score 0):

try to put (sender: UIButton) in your IBAction like this:

@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton)